# Phonegap application offline expiry

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there any way to check the expiry of a phonegap app even it is in offline? We should consider the use case that user can change the mobile date.

Comment: Please include more information. Did you mean expiry date? Are you setting the expiry date or is it generated?

Comment: yes, I want to set an expiry date. But even if the user changes the mobile date and time app should be expired based on the expiry date.